# Ignore whitespace getchar()

Tags: c, getchar

I am having trouble ignoring the whitespace/tab. When a user enters a character from a command prompt, it should only accept any characters except whitespace or tab spaces.

eg:

```
$ ./a.out Character: =
```

Then, it's `=`

if

```
$ ./a.out Character:      =
```

With bunch of spaces, then it should detect as `=`

I have already declared variable a.

```
char a;
printf("Character: ");
a = getchar();
```

Code:

```
while((a = getchar()) != EOF){
        if( a != ' ' || a != '\t'){
            a = getchar();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Change `char a;` to `int a;` as `EOF` is an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: As chux observed, `getchar()` returns type `int`, and you cannot successfully read the full range of possible characters if you assign that result to a variable of type `char`.  In fact (I add), you risk invoking implementation defined behavior by doing so.  In short, variable `a` should have type `int`.

With that said, it looks like you want something along these lines:

```
do {
    a = getchar();
} while (a == (unsigned char) ' ' || a == (unsigned char) '\t');
```

Note that `EOF`, differs from both `' '` and `'\t'`, so you can safely defer testing for it until after the loop.

Note also that if you want to ignore newlines and other whitespace characters too, then you might get good use out of the standard `isspace()` library function.

Comment: if I do not type whitespace or tab spaces, just =, the program detects that the character is "space" or "tab", not equal.

Comment: @user4538951, I do not understand what you're trying to say.  However, the code I presented works equally well whether the `=` character you type is preceded by whitespace or not.  After the loop exits, variable `a` will contain the value of the first input character that is neither a space nor a tab -- including if it is the first character read -- or it will contain `EOF` if the end of the stream was reached before any such character was read.

Comment: For complete functionality, it is important that `a` is an `int`.

Comment: I did just insert casts to `unsigned char`, however, as might conceivably be needed if the system's character encoding is something strange that assigns character codes greater than 127 to `' '` or `'\t'`.

Comment: @chux, you're right, as usual.  I will edit my answer to call that out.

Comment: Minor:  If `a` is type `int` then the `(unsigned char)` casts are certainly not needed as both `a` and `'\t'` are type `int`.  If `a` is type `char` then, if anything, casting `a` to type `unsigned char` might make sense, otherwise I do not see a need for them.  IAC, nice answer.

Comment: @chux, are `char` literals in fact *not* of type `char`?  Upon from promotion from `char` to `int`, negative values (if `char` is signed) remain negative, but `EOF` is the only negative value `getchar()` should ever return.

Comment: Answering my own question, `char` literals have type `int` in C.  However, the standard does say that the value of a (single-)character constant is "the one that results when an object with type char whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type int" (C99).  I take that to mean you *do* need the casts for complete safety against weird character encodings, because the `char` literals can have negative values.

Comment: `char` literals are always of type `int` (C++ differs here), negative values are converted to `unsigned char` by `getchar` and thus can be distinguished from `EOF`. The casts here aren't strictly necessary as `' '` and `'\n'` are guaranteed to be positive. It would be needed, for example, when checking for é in ISO-8859-1 ( 0xe9, `'\xe9'` is usually -23): `a == (unsigned char) '\xe9'` doesn't work without the cast.

Comment: @mafso, as I said, the casts are for protection against weird encodings.  In practice, I don't offhand know any encoding in which they could have negative values, so the casts are pretty pedantic, but C does not actually guarantee anything about that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, I thought, members of the basic character sets are guaranteed to be positive. I can't find the corresponding standard quote, though. Maybe I was just wrong. (Btw, I didn't criticize the answer, the cast _is_ necessary in some cases (see my last comment), so it can be included here as a matter of style and consistency, even if it isn't strictly necessary for `' '` and `'\n'` (what I'm not sure about, currently).)

Comment: @mafso §5.1.1.2 5 discusses "... escape sequence ... converted ...  (and) if there is no corresponding member ...execution character, it is converted to an  implementation defined member ...".  So LSNED that `'\xe9'` could become -23 or 233 or whatever, hence the value to a `(unsigned char) '\xe9'`.

Comment: @mafso  Minor: 1) "`char` literals are ..." is better stated as "character literals are ...".  2) "negative values are converted to `unsigned char` by `getchar` ..." is more like `getchar()` obtains the character as an `unsigned char` - it is not really negative to begin with - just a character.

Comment: @mafso Lastly, was not able to find spec or implication that "basic character sets are guaranteed to be positive" - even though it seems to be common practice.  Might be a good SO post?

Comment: @chux: wrt 1) and 2) I agree. About writing a question: As I don't find anymore what made me think that those characters are positive, I think it won't make a good question. I'm reading through 5.1.1.2 p5 (thanks!), 5.2.1 and 6.4.4.4, maybe I'll find it. (And currently I'm a little irritated about 6.4.4.4 p9, stating that the _value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence [of an unprefixed character constant] shall be in the range of representable values for [...] `unsigned char`_. To me, this sounds like `'\xe9'` shouldn't be negative, what it is with Gcc.)

Comment: @chux: 6.2.5 p3 _If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative._ As I understand it, with plain `char` being unsigned, they could be negative (because the conversion makes them positive), so I'm not entirely sure about my original claim. Anyway, I've found the quote :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 #include <ctype.h>

 int a;

 do
 {
     a = getchar();
 } while (isspace(a));
```

as `EOF` is not a whitespace character, you don't need to handle it specially.

You can put that in a little function of its own if you like:

```
int
getcharnospace()
{ 
    int a;
    do
    {
        a = getchar();
    } while (isspace(a));
    return a;
}
```

Comment: In your first code, it do not type whitespace or tab spaces, just `=`, it will just keep looping on and on.

Comment: @user4538951 it will only loop if `isspace(a)` returns 1, which will be if `a` is a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a;
while(a=getchar()){
       if(a==' ' || a=='\t')
             continue;
       else
             putchar(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `break`, you stop the `while` loop. Use `continue` instead:

```
while((a = getchar()) != EOF){
    if( a != ' ' || a != '\t') continue;
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `while()` loop body as

```
while((a = getchar()) != EOF){
        if( a == ' ' || a == '\t')
              continue;                // if space ot tab is detetected, scan for next input
         else
          {
             putchar(a);                 //neither a space nor a tab, print it.
             break;
          }
    }
```

Also, as the return type of `getchar()` is `int`, you should use `int a`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Space `' '` is not the only whitespace `char` in C.
2. Tab `'\t'` is one of C's whitespace `char`.
3. Use `int ch` rather than `char ch` to distinctly save all the different results from `getchar()`.
4. `isspace(EOF)` is always false.
5. Use `issapce()`, it is the C standard function for detecting white-space.

   ```
   // char a;
   int a;
   printf("Character: ");

   // All that is needed to consume white-space characters
   while(isspace(a = getchar()));
   ```